# Calling nested dependency in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have two class which using nested dependency. My class are `ExceptionHandler` and `JwtHelper`. `Startup.cs` call `ExceptionHandler`. Then `ExceptionHandler` call `JwtHelper`. But while I getting `exceptionHandler` in `startup.cs`, it gave me error 
**Unable to resolve service for type 'Hsys.WebToken.JwtHelper' while attempting to activate 'Hsys.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler'**

I added dependencies to `Startup.cs`. What can be reason of this error?

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSingleton<IJwtHelper, JwtHelper>();
    services.AddSingleton<IExceptionHandler, ExceptionHandler>();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => builder.Run(async context =>
    {    
        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();            
        //This line give me error while Getting Required Service
        IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IExceptionHandler>();
        await exceptionHandler.AddApplicationError(context, error);
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
    }));

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

ExceptionHandler.cs

```
public class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly JwtHelper jwtHelper;

    public ExceptionHandler(JwtHelper jwtHelper)
    {
        this.jwtHelper = jwtHelper;
    }

    public async Task AddApplicationError()
    {
        var userId = jwtHelper.GetValueFromToken("userId");
    }
}
```

JwtHelper.cs

```
public class JwtHelper : IJwtHelper
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public JwtHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetValueFromToken(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokens = handler.ReadToken(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]) as JwtSecurityToken;
        return tokens.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == propertyName).Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Registered `IJwtHelper` with the DI container, with a concrete class of `JwtHelper`.  However inside your exception handler you are telling the DI container you want `JwtHelper` injected.  You never registered `JwtHelper`, but its interface.  You want your `ExceptionHandler` class to look like this instead.

```
public class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly IJwtHelper jwtHelper;

    public ExceptionHandler(IJwtHelper jwtHelper)
    {
        this.jwtHelper = jwtHelper;
    }

    public async Task AddApplicationError()
    {
        var userId = jwtHelper.GetValueFromToken("userId");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @EMcg. I always focus of being nested. So, I can't see this basic syntax error and took my a lot of time.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir it happens to all of us!  Glad I could help.